# How to Moq this view?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, moq, mvp

I have a view for which I'd like to mock the `Show` behaviour.

[image: Authentication dialog]

Once the credentials have been entered, the [Connecter] button enables itself, and then the user can click. I wish I could reproduce this behaviour without having to show the view and actually really enter my credentials.

The application is a WinForms MDI presented by the `IApplicationPresenter`. The `IApplicationPresenter` raises the `ShowView` to which the `IApplicationView` subscribed.

Then, when the `IApplicationView.Shown`, the `IApplicationPresenter` forces the user to authenticate like this:

**IApplicationPresenter.OnViewShown**

```
public void OnViewShown() { forceAuthentication(); }

private void forceAuthentication() {
    IAuthenticationView authView = new AuthenticationView();
    IAuthenticationPrenseter authPresenter = new AuthenticationPresenter();
    authPresenter.ShowView();
}
```

It's like I can smell one thing.

1. It's just like I could inject the `IAuthenticationView` to the `IApplicationPresenter`. Then, this would allow me to inject my mocked view to it, and avoid the view being actually shown, which is in fact what I want to come up with. Is it the best way to make it?

Now, I want to test that when the `IApplicationView` is shown, the `IApplicationPresenter` is notified and forces authentication.

Any thoughts of a better approach in terms of mocking here?

> **UPDATE**

**IView**

```
public interface IView {
    void CloseView();
    void SetTitle(string title);
    void ShowView();
    void RaiseVoidEvent(VoidEventHandler @event);

    event VoidEventHandler OnViewInitialize;
    event VoidEventHandler OnViewShown;
}
```

**IApplicationView**

```
public interface IApplicationView : IView {
    void OnUserAuthenticated();

    event VoidEventHandler ManageRequestsClicked;
}
```

**IPresenter**

```
public interface IPresenter<V> where V : IView {
    V View { get; }
    IDatabaseUser CurrentUser { get; }

    void CloseView();
    void OnViewInitialize();
    void RaiseVoidEvent(VoidEventHandler @event);
    void ShowView();

    event VoidEventHandler OnCloseView;
    event VoidEventHandler OnShowView;
}
```

**Presenter**

```
public abstract class Presenter<V> : IPresenter<V> where V : IView {
    public Presenter(V view) {
        if (view == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("view");

        View = view;
        View.OnViewInitialize += OnViewInitialize;

        OnCloseView += View.CloseView;            
        OnShowView += View.ShowView;
    }

    public virtual IDatabaseUser CurrentUser { get; protected set; }
    public virtual V View { get; private set; }

    public virtual void CloseView() { RaiseVoidEvent(OnCloseView); }
    public virtual void OnViewInitialize() { }
    public void RaiseVoidEvent(VoidEventHandler @event) { if (@event != null) @event(); }
    public virtual void ShowView() { RaiseVoidEvent(OnShowView); }

    public virtual event VoidEventHandler OnCloseView;
    public virtual event VoidEventHandler OnShowView;
}
```

**IApplicationPresenter**

```
public interface IApplicationPresenter : IPresenter<IApplicationView> {
    IAuthenticationPresenter AuthenticationPresenter { get; set; }

    void OnManageRequestsClicked();
    void OnUserAuthenticated(UserAuthenticatedEventArgs e);
    void OnViewShown();
}
```

**ApplicationPresenter**

```
public class ApplicationPresenter : Presenter<IApplicationView>, IApplicationPresenter {
    public ApplicationPresenter(IApplicationView view) : this(view, null) { }
    public ApplicationPresenter(IApplicationView view, IAuthenticationPresenter authPresenter) : base(view) {
        AuthenticationPresenter = authPresenter;            
        View.OnViewShown += OnViewShown;
        View.ManageRequestsClicked += OnManageRequestsClicked;
    }

    public IAuthenticationPresenter AuthenticationPresenter { get { return authenticationPresenter; } set { setAuthenticationPresenter(value); } }

    public void OnManageRequestsClicked() {
        var requests = new GestionDemandeAccesInformationForm();
        requests.Database = database;
        requests.MdiParent = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)View;
        requests.Show();
    }

    public void OnUserAuthenticated(UserAuthenticatedEventArgs e) { 
        CurrentUser = new DatabaseUser(e.Login, e.Password, e.DatabaseInstance);
        database = new DatabaseSessionFactory(CurrentUser);
        setAppTitle();
        showRequestsManagementView();
    }

    public void OnViewShown() { forceAuthentication(); }
}
```

**IAuthenticationView**

```
public interface IAuthenticationView : IView {
    string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    string Instance { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<string> Instances { get; set; }
    string Login { get; set; }
    string Password { get; set; }

    void EnableConnectButton(bool enabled);
    void SetDefaultInstance(string defaultInstance);
    void RaiseSelectionChangedEvent(SelectionChangedEventHandler @event, SelectionChangedEventArgs e);

    event VoidEventHandler OnConnect;
    event SelectionChangedEventHandler OnDatabaseInstanceChanged;
    event VoidEventHandler OnLoginChanged;
    event VoidEventHandler OnPasswordChanged;
}
```

**IAuthenticationPresenter**

```
public interface IAuthenticationPresenter : IValidatablePresenter, IPresenter<IAuthenticationView> {
    void OnConnect();
    void OnViewDatabaseInstanceChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e);
    void OnViewLoginChanged();
    void OnViewPasswordChanged();
    void RaiseUserAuthenticatedEvent(UserAuthenticatedEventArgs e);
    event UserAuthenticatedEventHandler UserAuthenticated;
}
```

**AuthenticationPresenter**

```
public class AuthenticationPresenter : Presenter<IAuthenticationView>, IAuthenticationPresenter {
    public AuthenticationPresenter(IAuthenticationView view, IMembershipService service) : base(view) {
        MembershipService = service;
        View.ErrorMessage = null;
        View.SetTitle(ViewTitle);
        subscribeToEvents();
    }

    public bool IsValid { get { return credentialsEntered(); } }
    public IMembershipService MembershipService { get; set; }

    public virtual void OnConnect() {
        if (noDatabaseInstanceSelected()) display(MissingInstanceErrorMessage);
        else if (noLoginEntered()) display(MissingLoginErrorMessage);
        else if (noPasswordEntered()) display(MissingPasswordErrorMessage);
        else {
            display(EverythingIsFine);
            if (isAuthenticUser()) notifyTheApplicationThatTheUserIsAuthentic();
            else { display(InvalidLoginOrPasswordErrorMessage); }
        }
    }

    public override void OnViewInitialize() {
        base.OnViewInitialize();
        View.ErrorMessage = null;
        View.Instances = Configuration.DatabaseInstances;
        View.SetDefaultInstance(Configuration.DefaultInstance);
    }

    public void OnViewDatabaseInstanceChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e) { View.Instance = (string)e.Selected; }
    public void OnViewLoginChanged() { View.EnableConnectButton(IsValid); }
    public void OnViewPasswordChanged() { View.EnableConnectButton(IsValid); }
    public void RaiseUserAuthenticatedEvent(UserAuthenticatedEventArgs e) { if (UserAuthenticated != null) UserAuthenticated(e); }

    public event UserAuthenticatedEventHandler UserAuthenticated;
}
```

Comment: Your smell looks good to me. It's a good DI pattern IMO for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd inject a factory for creating `AuthenticationPresenter` and in your test I would call `OnViewShown()` and verify on your mock (of the presenter returned by the factory) that `ShowView` is called.

**EDIT**
Note that I haven't compiled this, I don't have a C# compiler right now.

Here is my version of the test. Based on my interpretation of what you really want to test :

```
[TestClass]
public class ApplicationPresenterTests 
{
    [TestClass]
    public class OnViewShown : ApplicationPresenterTests 
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ForceAuthentication() 
        {
            // given
            var authenticationPresenterFactory = new Mock<IAuthenticationPresenterFactory>();
            var authenticationPresenter = new Mock<IAuthenticationPresenter>();
            authenticationPresenterFactory.Setup(f => f.create()).Returns(authenticationPresenter.Object);
            var presenter = new ApplicationPresenter(authenticationPresenterFactory);

            // when
            presenter.OnViewShown();

            // then
            authenticationPresenter.Verify(p => p.ShowView());
        }
}
```

Comment: Although I can functionally understand your idea, might you provide some code sample to illustrate it concretely? What would your code for such purpose look like? Please, should you require more code sample based on my reality, do not hesitate, I'd be glad to provide you with it.

Comment: What part would you need clarifications with? The factory? The presenter? The test code?

Comment: +1 To ensure one gets all of it out of this question/answer, I would suggest all of it, so that the SO community may someday benefit from it.

Comment: What about the fact that I need a user to be instantiated within the `ApplicationPresenter` based on the comment I wrote to my answer? Perhaps will you have a better understanding of what I am trying to test. And perhaps I'm mixing two things up, first that I actually show the authentication view through the authentication presenter. Second, that I have an instance of `IDatabaseUser` instance kept in my application presenter on successful login? What do you think?

Comment: My guess would be that your test scope is too big. I would have 1 unit test for a ApplicationPresenter that would test that my user is forced to authenticate `OnViewShown()`. And then I would have another unit test for my authenticationPresenter, that would test, let's say, `onSuccessfulLogin()` that the user retrieved from the database is sent to ApplicationPresenter. Furthermore, you could do an integration test, that'd mock the database, and test the whole thing, if needed.

Comment: I do like your idea. I believe I have based my unit test on a functional or behavioural test. I agree the scope of my test is to big then, hence the complexity enhanced out of it, and the trouble I had to get it working. Based on these new information, I'd appreciate if you could set an instance up and update your answer accordingly, if you don't mind. I'm aware this requires much of your time, and I am grateful to you for your kind assistance.

Comment: Set an instance of what?

Comment: `IApplicationPresenter.CurrentUser` is an instance of `IDatabaseUser`. The `IDatabaseUser` contains the informaiton presented in my `IAuthenticationView`.

Comment: Maybe if you give me the real code, otherwise it'll be kind of hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have come up with this solution which works flawlessly.

It's all about setting up the mock object to work as expected.

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class ApplicationPresenterTests {
    [TestClass]
    public class OnViewShown : ApplicationPresenterTests {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ForceAuthentication() {
            // arrange

            // act
            Presenter.OnViewShown();
            var actual = Presenter.CurrentUser;

            // assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, typeof(IDatabaseUser));
        }
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void ApplicationMainPresenterSetUp() {
        Mock<IAuthenticationView> authView = new Mock<IAuthenticationView>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        authView.SetupProperty(v => v.ErrorMessage);
        authView.SetupGet(v => v.Instance).Returns(RandomValues.RandomString());
        authView.SetupGet(v => v.Login).Returns(RandomValues.RandomString());
        authView.SetupGet(v => v.Password).Returns(RandomValues.RandomString());
        authView.Setup(v => v.CloseView());
        authView.Setup(v => v.SetTitle(It.IsAny<string>()));
        authView.Setup(v => v.ShowView()).Raises(v => v.OnConnect += null).Verifiable();

        Mock<IMembershipService> authService = new Mock<IMembershipService>(MockBehavior.Loose);
        authService.Setup(s => s.AuthenticateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

        IAuthenticationPresenter authPresenter = new AuthenticationPresenter(authView.Object, authService.Object);

        ApplicationView = new ApplicationForm();

        Presenter = new ApplicationPresenter(ApplicationView, authPresenter);
    }

    protected IApplicationView ApplicationView { get; private set; }
    protected IApplicationPresenter Presenter { get; private set; }
}
```

Therefore, the key change was to inject the dependancy of an `IAuthenticationPresenter` into the `IApplicationPresenter`, hence the `ApplicationPresenter` constructor overload.

Though this has solved my problem, I better understand the need for a `PresenterFactory` being injected into the `ApplicationPresenter`, since this is the presenter which handles everything in the application, that is, the calls to other views for each which has its own presenter.

Before me lies an even more complex challenge to take on. Stay tuned!

Comment: What did you want to test exactly with that test? I don't see any assertion/verify. IMO I would just test that, when the view is shown, it forces the user to authenticate. (if that's the case...)

Comment: Actually, my acceptance criteria is to have an instance of the authenticated user kept within my `ApplicationPresenter` so that the login may further be used for auditing. The current project has the notion of accept/reject an object of a certain state based on user-criterion, that is, when the user accepts a report, let's say, I need to provide this very report with the user login to mark the appropriate field with it, in addition to a `DateTime` that informs on when the occurence was accepted. That is why I expect to have a current user as shown in my test.

Comment: Furthermore, my actual real-life test is divided into two different tests, one that verifies that everything that has been setup is actually used as I expected it, and the other shown here that simply check for my current user being instantiated within the application presenter on successful login, which I force using the `Mock<IMembershipService>` instance that returns `true` whatever it is passed to.