# How to use the Factory pattern with Generics?

Tags: c#, generics, mvp, factory-pattern

I wish to create a PresenterFactory that would be responsible, obviously, for the creation of presenter instances.

Based on code sample provided in this question:

[**How to Moq this view?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669972/how-to-moq-this-view)

and @Pacane's answer, I thought I would go this way:

**PresenterFactoryTests**

```
[TestClass]
public class PresenterFactoryTests {
    [TestClass]
    public class Instance : PresenterFactoryTests {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ReturnsInstantialized() {                
            // arrange
            Type expected = typeof(PresenterFactory);

            // act
            PresenterFactory actual = PresenterFactory.Instance;

            // assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, expected);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ReturnsSame() {
            // arrange
            PresenterFactory expected = PresenterFactory.Instance;

            // act
            PresenterFactory actual = PresenterFactory.Instance;

            // assert
            Assert.AreSame(expected, actual);
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class Create : PresenterFactoryTests {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ReturnsAuthenticationPresenter { 
            // arrange
            Type expected = typeof(IAuthenticationPresenter);

            // act
            IAuthenticationPresenter actual = 
                PresenterFactory
                    .Instance
                    .Create<IAuthenticationPresenter, IAuthenticationView>(
                        new MembershipService());

           // assert
           Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actual, expected);
        }

        // Other tests here...
    }
}
```

**PresenterFactory**

```
public sealed PresenterFactory {
    private PresenterFactory() { }

    public static PresenterFactory Instance { get { return getInstance(); } }

    P Create<P, V>(params object[] args) where P : IPresenter<V> where V : IView { 
        V view = (V)Activator.CreateInstance<V>();
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(P), view, args);
    }

    private static PresenterFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new PresenterFactory();
        return instance;
    }

    private static PersenterFactory instance;
}
```

**ApplicationPresenter**

```
public class ApplicationPresenter : Presenter<IApplicationView>, IApplicationPresenter {
    public ApplicationPresenter(IApplicationView view, PresenterFactory presenters)
        : base (view) {
        Presenters = presenters;

        // other initializing stuff here...
    }      
}
```

However, because of the type constraints, it seems that I am unable to do so as stated in the test above-mentioned.

In my `PresenterFactoryTests.Create.ReturnsAuthenticationPresenter` test method, when I use interfaces as type parameters, it compiles and throws on runtime becuase the `Activator.CreateInstance` can't create an instance of an interface.

Aside, if I input the concrete types, it complains that it cannot explicitely convert type to my type constraints, albeit both implements the given interfaces.

The `PresenterFactory` is required by the `ApplicationPresenter`, I shall inject it through its constructor so that the application may instantiate all the available presenters depending on the feature being asked by the user.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know if you're using a dependency injector, but I personally use Ninject with its extension that generates factories for you. https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out Ninject. I have already used it in the past. I didn't come to think of it before your share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need one more generic argument - concrete type of view because you need 2 concrete types (view and presenter to be able to create them) and type of view's interface:

```
P Create<P, V, IV>(params object[] args) 
      where P : IPresenter<V> where V :IV, IV: IView {
```

Comment: +1 For coming up with a neat solution. Sometimes the simpler solutions  are the ones we think the least. =P  I am concerned about ease of use. I personally think that giving multiple type arguments is easy enough for code reuse for someone who could be unaware of how a factory works, hence my thoughts about registering which adds, IMHO, complexity over use. I find it more valuable and natural for a programmer to use multiple type parameters, and providing the right arguments in the `args` object array. What are your thoughts on the topic, please?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller - for creation of objects I'd use DI container as mentioned in comments. If using this for factory I will not try to spend time on hiding types from code because usage is limited to very small portion of the code and that "setup my dependencies" code tends to have a lot of "magic" already. For other usages - if types can't be automatically detected by compiler I'd try to find another solution.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Note: you may try to post it to http://CodeReview.stackexchange.com to see if there is better solution. I personally don't like how your method gives no hints about what would happen with arguments (will they be passed to constructor of one/both/neither types, will some magical matching happen,...). Maybe some fluid interface would work better `Using<P, V, IV>().ViewParm(viewConstructorArgs).PresenterParm(args).Build()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about CodeReview. I shall submit it. As per having no clue about my `args`, perhaps giving it a more meaningful name like `presenterCtorArgs` would be more suitable. As for the DI container, I shall certainly take an eye out soon. The fact is that I must urge the delivery now. =(